# Touch event locations are off

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, d3.js

Friends - I'm implementing a drawing app using React/Redux & D3. The mouse events are handled with relative ease. However, the touch events have become a challenge. Touch-start, touch-move, & touch-end all return x & y values that are consistently off. The sample code is given below:

```js
  function handleTouchStart(event) {
    const currentLocation = d3.pointer(event.changedTouches[0]);
    handleStartEvent(currentLocation);
  }
```

The current location above is wrong. What is missing? Your help would be appreciated.

Thank You